# Refactoring code to implement ES6 Modules broke Github Pages (404)

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages, es6-modules

I was hosting a demo of a canvas game I'm working on and everything was working smoothly until I decided to separate my code into modules using ES6 module syntax.
I use import statements like `import canvas, { ctx } from "/canvas.js";` and export them with

```
export default canvas;
export { ctx };
```

When I run the program through local server, everything works perfectly, but when I try my link to my Github Pages live demo, all of the modules except for the main program `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>` give me 404 errors. How do I fix this?

Comment: 404 means it can't find the files,  and a slash `/` at the start of a url means the root of the website, I've a feeling you have not put your app on GitHub's root..  So your probably after a relative path like `import canvas, { ctx } from "./canvas.js";`

Comment: In Github Pages, don't you always have a project name in the directory structure?  So, you either have to load a file without any path (implicitly from the same path as the web page came from) or you have to put the actual path into the URL.  So, you can't use `/canvas.js` because Github pages doesn't let you put files at the room of your domain, only in a specific project.  So, you probably want either just `canvas.js` or `/yourProjectName/canvas.js`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm confused, if I do canvas.js or /projectName/canvas.js, won't that just make it break on local server? I've tried ./canvas.js, canvas.js, and /projectName/canvas.js and nothing is working...

Comment: @Keith Do you have anything else to try? It didn't work

Comment: Yes, that would break locally.  The WHOLE point here is that unless you configure your local server to use the same directory structure as your GitHub pages somehow, then you can't use the identical code in both places.  I had this same issue when I worked on a big GitHub pages project.  I actually wrote a little utility to post process links for local usage or for GitHub pages usage because the URL structure is just different.

Comment: @jfriend00 I figured it out and it didn't even break the local server version. My script element's src file path was js/app.js when it should've been ./js/app/js. Anyway, thanks for the answers.

Comment: @fishgas  That's what I said, use relative paths.

Comment: @Keith I thought js/app.js is relative though. Isn't it exactly the same as ./js/app.js?